# pip install error - ImportError: No module named finsymbols

Tags: python, pip

When I run:

```
sudo -H pip install finsymbols
```

I get the below response:

> Requirement already satisfied: finsymbols in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
>   Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4>=4.2.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from finsymbols)

then when I run

```
$ python 
>>> from finsymbols import symbols
```

I get

> File "", line 1, in 
>   ImportError: No module named finsymbols

My question is, why am I getting the error when the module is installed?

Comment: try install suing pip3 maybe the python version giving error

Comment: Please keep pip out of your system files, install with --user instead of using sudo

Comment: Please use sudo apt-get install  for installing system packages

Comment: Just to chime in as well, the problem seems to be that your pip call installs the package to a different destination than where python is looking.
Now might be a good point to start using virtualenv for development, that way you can retain full control over what you install and where you look for it. http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/#lower-level-virtualenv

Comment: Are `python -V` and `pip -V` the same? If not, try using `python -m pip` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You may have multiple versions of Python.

Requirement already satisfied: finsymbols in /usr/local/lib/**python2.7**/dist-packages Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4>=4.2.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from finsymbols)

Pip has installed it in python2.7 path. Your default Python may be different.

So try using

```
$ python2.7
```

instead of

```
$ python
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install a module that runs on Python 3.x, you need to use

```
pip3 install module_name
```

Or link the `pip3` executable in `/usr/bin` to replace `pip`. In this way, you can use `pip` to install Python 3.x modules.

Here I strongly recommend to use `virtualenv` to manage your Python module environments. More details can be found [here](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks jonatan, that worked.

I ran

```
pip install finsymbols
```

not

```
sudo -H pip install finsymbols
```

and that fixed the issue